# SWRevealViewController - Get height of rear view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm finding a way to get the height of the rear view, I need it because I'm using this code to show and hide an activity indicator:

```
    func showActivityIndicator() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loadingView = UIView()
        self.loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        print("Width: \(self.revealViewController().view.frame.width)")
        print("Height: \(self.revealViewController().view.frame.height)")
        self.loadingView.center = self.view.center
        self.loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#111111")
        self.loadingView.alpha = 0.9
        self.loadingView.clipsToBounds = true


        self.spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
        self.spinner.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 80.0, height: 80.0)
        self.spinner.center = CGPoint(x:self.loadingView.bounds.size.width / 2, y:self.loadingView.bounds.size.height / 2)

        self.loadingView.addSubview(self.spinner)
        self.view.addSubview(self.loadingView)
        self.spinner.startAnimating()
    }
}

func hideActivityIndicator() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.spinner.stopAnimating()
        self.loadingView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

But is not showing the activity on the all size of the rear view, just on the size of the device.

Here two pictures from above and below.

[image] [image]

Maybe exits another way to do it or advices that I could use to fix it.

Thank you for the help,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to find some property in

```
self.swrevealviewcontroller.height
```

I use it long time ago and i remember that there is a property, im almost sure!

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm using `self.revealViewController().view.frame.height` but it return the height of the device and not the height  of the scroll view inside the rear view